# Synchronise array stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've just tried using an updated version of my app on an iPhone which has the version installed that is currently on the app store. I have added a few new features since the last update which seems to cause the app to crash.

Basically, I added a new array that stores data for notes which was not present in previous versions and this is stored in NSUserDefaults (Not ideal, I know, but I would rather keep it this way for now)

This is the code I have in my table view where the app crashes:

```
cell.notesLabel.text = (notes.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)) as? String
```

The error just states - "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" as soon as the table view tab is tapped.

I was discussing this with someone else and they suggested that I need to check for the existence of the array in the defaults and create and synchronise it if it is missing.

I've only been programming for a few months so this doesn't mean a whole lot to me. But I assume I would just need do something like this:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") == nil {
  //Do something?
}
```

I'm unsure about what he means by synchronise? Anyone have any suggestions?

At the moment in `viewWillAppear()` I have this code:

```
    if var tempNames: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("names") {
        names = tempNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempDates: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("dates") {
        dates = tempDates.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempValues: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("values") {
        values = tempValues.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempImages: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("images") {
        images = tempImages.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempUnformatted: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("unformatted") {
        unformatted = tempUnformatted.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
    if var tempNotes: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") {
        notes = tempNotes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
```

EDIT:

I tried changing my code to this, but I have the same issue:

```
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") != nil {
        var tempNotes: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes")!
        notes = tempNotes.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
    }
```

Comment: You always need to call the synchronize method after saving any data  with NSUserDefaults. Check the class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: No you don't. NSUserDefaults will automatically synchronize after a few seconds, or when the app is quitting (and on iOS 8/Yosemite it's a few milliseconds rather than seconds). Synchronizing early is only useful if you need it done before then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet to get you started. I checked it into the playground and it works:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var array = ["Eggs", "Milk", "Bread"]

defaults.setObject(array, forKey: "notes")

var notes = [String]()

if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("notes") != nil {

    notes = defaults.objectForKey("notes") as Array
}
```

You can synch while testing but I doubt you need it for the release build:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
```

Comment: I've just got around to having a look at this, but I've been having issues with integrating the code you suggested into my app. I've updated my question with some extra code that I have in `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: There's a flaw in the logic above. You're testing for `var tempNames` while declaring it. It won't have the opportunity to be equal to the data stored in standardUserDefaults() at that point. What I think you mean is `if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("names") != nil`

Comment: I gave that a try (code above) and it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. It still crashes on the same line.